# jsoup working with large html files

Tags: java, html, memory-management, jsoup

What is the best way to work with large html files (10mb/20mb) that I've just downloaded?

Actually `Jsoup.parse(response.body())` requires a lot of memory (sometimes it goes `OutOfMemoryError`) and in any case requires a lot of time (1-3 seconds).

I've rejected to use regex (not the best way to manipulate html), so how can I improve this process?

Thanks!

P. S. It's excluded the raise of the heap over than 1gb

Comment: Do you know the structure of  your html file?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/339

Comment: @Dimitri yes, basically a table, i need only some starting pattern td ids